# My Windows 7 system restore(rstui.exe) is malfunctioning, how to fix it?

Tags: windows-7

As my image shows: 
[image]

Another symptom is: [Using Wmic to create a restore point](http://winaero.com/blog/create-a-restore-point-in-windows-10-with-one-click/)

```
Wmic.exe /Namespace:\\root\default Path SystemRestore Call CreateRestorePoint "%DATE%", 100, 7
```

will report a very vague error message:

> The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

[image]

The mere thing that works is the [Create...] button in System Properties -> [System Protection] tab, and it really creates a restore point so that I can retrieve historical files from file property dialog -> [Previous Versions].

BTW: This a virtual machine, so I can try anything on it while still preserving the faulty spot(by VM snapshot), and any suggestions to diagnose the problem are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same errors. 
The reason was that in System Protection - Protection Settings - C:, I had selected (o) Only restore previous versions of files.

This seems to prohibit scheduled creation of restore points.

Once I changed it to (o) Restore system settings and previous versions of files, the errors stopped.